# How to add to the Undo Stack in PowerPoint programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint

I am programmatically changing the fill color of the selected shapes in a powerpoint slide. I also allow the user to keep "live previewing" changes in a custom task pane. For example,

1. User selects a shape.
2. Changes the color of the selected shape by clicking on a color in a custom pane.
3. Repeats step 2 till satisfied.
4. Presses Undo.

The problem is, when undo is clicked, it **goes back the original color**, ignoring all the colors the user cycled through. Is there a way to manipulate the undo stack to allow for going back through the colors **one-by-one** instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Application.StartNewUndoEntry() API available starting with PowerPoint 2010.

Comment: Works fine, but could include an example.

Comment: A nice example from Shyam Pillai:  http://skp.mvps.org/2010/ppt016.htm

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen any hint that PPT gives access to the undo stack.  You might instead want to implement your own stack and give the user a Previous button in the custom pane.